# Struggling with a project in python

Tags: python, loops, file-io

My assignment is to make this program. A program that reads `tests.txt`, displays all of the scores, and the average of the scores. This program must also use a loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():

   scorefile = open('test.txt', 'r')

   test1 = scorefile.readline()
   test2 = scorefile.readline()
   test3 = scorefile.readline()
   test4 = scorefile.readline()
   test5 = scorefile.readline()

   scorefile.close()

   print(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5)

   total = (test1 + test2 + test3+ test4 + test5) / 5.0

   print('The average test score is:', total)
main()
```

I wrote to the `test.txt` file already with these numbers:

```
95
87
79
91
86
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please be sure to ask an actual question so we'll know specifically how we can help you.

Comment: By default, the values are stored in the local variables as strings. You would have to cast them to float or int for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

So assume you have this file:

```
95
87
79
91
86
```

In any language, we need to:

1. Open the file;
2. Read the values in the file by looping over all the lines in the file until the file is exhausted;
3. Deal with each value (they may need to be converted to an int from a string for example)
4. Add up all the values read then divide by the number of values read.

In Python, that recipe is translated to:

```
nums=list()                      # we will hold all the values in a list                           
with open(fn, 'r') as f:         # open the file and establish an iterator over the lines
    for n in f:                  # iterate over the lines
        nums.append(int(n))      # read a line, convert to int, append to the list
```

At the interactive prompt, you can 'print' nums:

```
>>> nums
[95, 87, 79, 91, 86]
```

Now you can print `nums` and average the numbers:

```
print nums, sum(nums)/len(nums)
[95, 87, 79, 91, 86] 87
```

If you want to print `nums` differently, use join:

```
print '\n'.join(map(str, nums))
```

or

```
print '\t'.join(map(str, nums))
```

Perhaps a more idiomatic way to write it in Python specifically might be:

```
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    nums=map(int, f)
    print nums, sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

There is a whole different discussion to be had if the file might be too big to fit into the memory of the computer.

For big files, you just need to keep a running total and a count, and you do not need to load the entire file into memory. In Python, you could do:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    num_sum=0
    for i, s in enumerate(f, 1):
        print s.strip()
        num_sum+=int(s)

    print '\n', num_sum/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented the code, so you can understand the process step by step:

```
# first, let's open the file
# we use with so that it automatically closes
# after leaving its scope
with open("test.txt", "r") as readHere:
    # we read the file and split by \n, or new lines
    content = readHere.read().split("\n")
    # store scores here
    scores = []
    # count is the number of scores we have encountered
    count = 0
    # total is the total of the scores we've encountered
    total = 0
    # now, loop through content, which is a list
    for l in content:
        count += 1          # increment the scores seen by one
        total += int(l)     # and increase the total by the number on this line
        scores.append(int(l))   # add to list
    #one the loop has finished, print the result
    print("average is " + str(total/count) + " for " + str(count) + " scores")
    # print the actual scores:
    for score in scores:
        print(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

**General approach**

```
def myAssignmentOnLOOPs():
    aScoreFILE = open( "tests.txt", "r" )
    aSumREGISTER = 0
    aLineCOUNTER = 0
    for aLine in aScoreFILE.readlines():   # The Loop:
        aLineCOUNTER += 1                  #     count this line
        aSumREGISTER += int( aLine )       #     sum adds this line, converted to a number
        print aLine                        #     print each line as task states so
    # FINALLY:
    aScoreFILE.close()                     # .close() the file 
    if ( aLineCOUNTER != 0 ):              # If() to avoid DIV!0 error
        print "Finally, the Sum: ", aSumREGISTER
        print "          an Avg: ", aSumREGISTER / aLineCOUNTER
    else:
        print "There were no rows present in file:tests.txt"
```